# Validar entrada tipos de datos

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main() {

    int num;
    printf("%d\n",__INT_MAX__); //2147483647 

    printf("Introduce un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("%d",num);

    return 0;
}
```

Si introduzco mas del rango postivo de int 2147483647 por ejemplo 999999999999999999999 o si introduzco letras en vez de numeros puede dejar de funcionar. Como puedo limitar o validar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [`int scanf(const char *format, ...)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

De la definición de la cabecera de función puesta arriba podemos deducir que el valor retornado por `scanf` puede significar varias cosas, entre ellas, lo que dice el estándar:

> [**7.21.6.4p3**:](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4p3) The `scanf` function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

En resumen, en español: `scanf` puede retornar `EOF` en caso de error o el numero de argumentos *"parseados"* correctamente; el mismo numero puede ser cero.

Tomemos en cuenta el código en tu pregunta:

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

Como buena practica, lo mas recomendable es evaluar el resultado de esa llamada:

```
if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
  printf("%d fue leido correctamente!\n", num);
}
else printf("no pude leer la variable num.\n");
```

No es del todo necesario, pero si quieres validar la entrada que lees desde el teclado, vas a necesitar hacer algo similar; otra forma de compararlo es:

```
switch (scanf("%d", &num)) {
  case EOF: printf("Ha ocurrido un error interno.\n"); break;
  case 0: printf("No se han escaneado valores."); break;
  default: /* Haz algo para cada argumento. */ break;
}
```

E ir agregando los casos en los que necesites comparar.

> Un inciso al respecto con `scanf` y los enteros: la función `scanf` no retornara un valor de error en caso de que un valor sea mayor al rango permitido por ese tipo de dato, `scanf` intentara *parsearlo* y posteriormente asignarlo, independientemente de si el tipo de destino es lo suficientemente grande como para guardar dicho valor.
>
> ---
>
> Si quieres validar que un valor encaja dentro del rango de un numero, vas a tener que implementar tu propio control, leyendo los caracteres a mano para luego verificar su valor o con alguna otra forma que se te ocurra.

Referencias:

- [Estándar C11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4p3)
- [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)
- [Respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8827449/5622844)

Saludos :)